# Trying to get the user-agent from request in asp.net web api self host

Tags: asp.net-web-api, self-hosting

I'm trying to get the user-agent in a web api self host and I'm either doing it wrong, or the web api itself is altering the user agent string.

I've tried using several methods to the get the string and they all return the same results, instead of the excepted "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.28 Safari/537.31", I only get "Mozilla/5.0".

I've tried:

```cs
var header = request.Headers.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Key == "User-Agent").Value.First();

var header = request.Headers.UserAgent.SingleOrDefault().Product.ToString();

var header = request.Headers.GetValues("User-Agent").FirstOrDefault();
```

Am I doing this wrong, it's self host so I don't have a context to work with.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The absolutely simplest way to get the full user-agent from inside a WebAPI-controller is by doing this:

```
var userAgent = Request.Headers.UserAgent.ToString();
```

It gives **exactly the same result** as doing the manual step like this:

```
// var headers = request.Headers.GetValues("User-Agent");
// var userAgent = string.Join(" ", headers);
```

Answer (score 8):

## **.NET Core 2.0(+)**

As Simple as `Request.Headers["User-Agent"]` (returns as string) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Oops, figured it out, answering it myself in case anyone else runs into this. Apparently the user-agent gets chopped up.

This gives me the full user-agent:

```cs
// Default empty user agent.
String userAgent = "";

// Get user agent.
if (Request.Headers.Contains("User-Agent"))
{
    var headers = request.Headers.GetValues("User-Agent");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var header in headers)
    {
        sb.Append(header);

        // Re-add spaces stripped when user agent string was split up.
        sb.Append(" ");
    }

    userAgent = sb.ToString().Trim();
}
```

Comment: That is an extreme over-complication. Just `ToString` the `Request.Headers.UserAgent` to get the same result.

Comment: Or just Request.UserAgent.

Comment: user1154664, Request.UserAgent isn't part of System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage.

Comment: Also, seriously, it's even an over complication of string concatenation; in the future, just use `string.Join` for such purposes. (Not that it's even necessary in this case!)

Answer (score 0):

```
var context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
HttpRequestBase request = context.Request;
var browserdetail = request.UserAgent;
```

This worked for me if you want only browser name then simply write:

```
var browserdetail = request.browser
```

And if you want clients ip address then simply do:

`var browserdetail = request.hostaddress` and use it for 
        generating token key for authenticaton.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple try the following. It's shorter and less likely to break.

```
String userAgent;
userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
```

It will give you a string similar to this one.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/6.0)
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2

Comment: `System.Web.HttpRequest` is a Request for ASP.NET WebForms/MVC and is **not** used in ASP.NET WebApi.

Comment: Ah gotcha, did not realize that. Thanks.