# Material ui server rendering warning

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, material-ui

I have sample template (react, material-ui, asp core) with server rendering. I've source here https://github.com/Stoope/ASP_CORE_REACT. When I run the app I get warning in f12 tool console

> React attempted to reuse markup in a container but the checksum was
>   invalid. This generally means that you are using server rendering and
>   the markup generated on the server was not what the client was
>   expecting. React injected new markup to compensate which works but you
>   have lost many of the benefits of server rendering. Instead, figure
>   out why the markup being generated is different on the client or
>   server:  (client) ng:0px 24px;display:flex;justify-content  (server)
>   ng:0px 24px;display:-webkit-box,-moz-box

when i set useAgent: 'all' in Layout.tsx

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  userAgent: 'all',
});
```

it works without warnings but toolbar layout seems broken

Comment: take a look here and try some of the solutions: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/4466

Comment: I can't run request.headers['user-agent'] on server side coz i'm not using NodeJS to handle requests

Comment: I haven't read everything in the issue I linked above so I don't know the context exactly, but according to this it's possible to get the user agent headers in asp.net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309304/trying-to-get-the-user-agent-from-request-in-asp-net-web-api-self-host or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664770/how-to-get-user-browser-name-user-agent-in-asp-net-core

Comment: But how can I send variable from asp.net to NodeJS?