# 'Mozilla/5.0' User Agent retuned when expecting 'googlebot' when using Request.Headers.GetValues("User-Agent").First()

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am using Request.Headers.GetValues("User-Agent").First() within a Web API method and getting 'Mozilla/5.0' when I am certain the crawler and User Agent is 'googlebot'.

I am using IIS Rewrite to arrive at this application and method, might this be causing the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16792380/20058276. For url rewrite issues, you can enable failed request tracing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules.